# Styling a column in a mediawiki-table

Tags: css, mediawiki

Is it possible to style a column in a mediawiki table?

I know how to style a cell, but I don't know how to style a column. I would like to give a background color to the whole column.

For instance:

```
{| class="wikitable"
! a
! b
|-
| c
| d
|}
```

I want to make the first column (with a and c in it) blue.

Comment: Mediawiki do not support `<col>`, `<colgroup>`. You have to use a `.css` file (if possible) or inline the style every cell use it. [reference](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Tables#Common_attributes_for_columns.2C_column_groups_and_row_groups)

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki does not support `col` or `colgroup` elements [at this time](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T2986) so you'll have to use CSS selectors, or duplicate the styles on every cell (probably a bad idea). With CSS it would look something like this:

```
table.firstcolumnblue td:first-child {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

You can put the CSS in `MediaWiki:Common.css` (admins only) or you can use the brand new [TemplateStyles extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TemplateStyles) to allow normal editors to write CSS rules.